# Creating a child theme for HTML5 Blank

Tags: html, wordpress, themes

I have just installed the HTML5 Blank theme on my WordPress install.

http://html5blank.com/

I have tried to create a child theme for it using the @import method shown on the WordPress codex.

```
/*
Theme Name: html5blank-child
Description: Child theme for HTML5 Blank
Template: html5blank-stable
Author: James
*/

@import url("../html5blank-stable/style.css");
```

It does not work, any CSS I add to the child theme does not overwrite the parent.

Help!

James

Answer (score 8):

HTML5Blank is not a 'child theme friendly' theme by default.

This is because it's a 'blank' template and is typically intended to be edited directly, but as you're all likely to want to retain your work beyond and parent theme updates, on your individual sites, we'll have to make your HTML5Blank theme into a parent theme and therefore child-theme-friendly.

As you will recall, (with a child-theme-friendly parent theme), you're able to create a child theme by adding a folder called HTML5Blank-child and add to that a **style.css** file that will hold your customizations and you'd also add a functions.php to also then hold any custom functions you may want, (note, you can't just copy the parent theme **functions.php** file over to your child theme folder, because you'd be initializing ALL the functions again, which will overload your page).

Look out for **get_template_directory_uri()** function vs. **get_stylesheet_directory_uri()** function to see if the theme you're considering is 'child-theme-friendly', (and in HTML5Blank's case, it uses the **get_template_directory_uri()** function to enqueue it's stylesheet, which means it's not), you'll then want to add some functionality to your newly created **functions.php** in your child theme (HTML5Blank-stable-child) and include the code below :

```
    <?php
    // De-register HTML5 Blank styles
    function html5blank_styles_make_child_active()
    {
    wp_deregister_style('html5blank'); // Enqueue it!
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'html5blank_styles_make_child_active', 100); // Add Theme Child Stylesheet

    // Load HTML5 Blank Child styles
    function html5blank_styles_child()
    {
    wp_register_style('html5blank-child', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('html5blank-child'); // Enqueue it!
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'html5blank_styles_child'); // Add Theme Child Stylesheet
    ?>
```

You'll then see that we've DE-REGISTERED the enqueuing of the HTML5Blank style sheet and then REGISTERED the child style sheet so it will then be allowed to work as an override to the main style sheet. 
The main style sheet it still in use, but the child theme now has the correct priority to work as an override. And lastly, we've not edited the parent theme at all, to achieve this outcome.

Once the above is in place, you should then see a line similar to the one below in your site source code :

```
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='html5blank-child-css'  href='/3.9.2/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable-child/style.css?ver=1.0' media='all' />
```

A second simple CSS rule to visually test can be added, (temporarily), to your child theme **style.css** file :

```
    body {
    font:300 11px/1.4 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#444;
    background:#f00 !important;
    }
```

You'll then see that we've DE-REGISTERED the enqueuing of the HTML5Blank style sheet and then REGISTERED the child style sheet so it will then be allowed to work as an override to the main style sheet. The main style sheet it still in use, but the child theme now has the correct priority to work as an override.

And lastly, we've not edited the parent theme at all, to achieve this outcome.

You should see the a red background as a result.

That then will allow you to continue editing in the child theme, and still be able to update the HTML5Blank theme in future too, which is 100% in keeping with how best to work with WordPress.

Comment: This should be a marked as the solution. As Lee has stated HTML5Blank is not really child theme friendly but this does solve the issue and allow for the child css to be prioritized.

Answer (score -1):

On the Template, try removing the "-stable". This is just a guess. The @import url is fine because that's what folder the theme is in.

Comment: Hi Bryan, I think the issue is something to do with the parent themes functions.php enqueuing the parent themes style.css:

Comment: // Load HTML5 Blank styles
function html5blank_styles()
{
    wp_register_style('normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/normalize.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('normalize'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_style('html5blank', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('html5blank'); // Enqueue it!
}

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue. That's they way parent themes should be load their styles. Did you try removing the _-stable_ from your style sheet?